# How to read Integer from a file with NIO and not to get BufferUnderflowException?

Tags: java, nio

What's wrong with this code? :

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
FileChannel channel = cacheFile.getChannel();
int bytesCount = channel.read(byteBuffer, offset);
int value = byteBuffer.getInt();
```

The last line always throws BufferUnderflowException.
Variable bytesCount contains 4.

What do I miss here?

Comment: Can you show us code that completely compiles?

Comment: @tieTYT: here's a bigger piece of code with reading and writing http://pastebin.com/4qPQkRAX

Comment: @tieTYT: it's used the next way: 1st step calls sync(0), 2nd step calls getSolution(0, 0). //getSolution contains intentional bug in the 1st lines to omit cache and use NIO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use an absolute get or rewind the buffer before reading:

```
// option 1
int value = byteBuffer.getInt(0);

// option 2
buffer.rewind();
int value = byteBuffer.getInt();
```

Although the docs are not immediately obvious (you have to click links until you get to [ReadableByteChannel.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29)), reads into a buffer changes the buffer's position.

Answer (score 0):

You must flip() the buffer before getting data out of it with either get() or write().